# PHP: String not appending

Tags: php, api

I'm building up a url to execute with curl. the url will call an api for the LMS that I'm using. Before being able to call anything else, you need to receive a token from the LMS to put in the url. I have gotten the token from the api, and I can echo it and it shows up just fine, when I echo the url after appending the token to it, it doesn't show up.

```
curl_setopt($c, 'CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER', true);
$res = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);

$start = strpos($res,"<token>");
$end = $start+37;
$token = substr($res,$start+7,$end-$start);

echo "{$token}<br />";

$url = "/www/api2.php?action=create_user";
$url .= "&login=" . urlencode($username);
$url .= "&password=" . urlencode($password);
$url .= "&name=" . urlencode($data['first_name']);
$url .= "&surname=" . urlencode($data['last_name']);
$url .= "&email=" . urlencode($email);
$url .= "&languages=english";
$url .= "&token=" . $token;

echo "{$url}<br />";
```

Output of the `echo "{$url}<br />";`

> /www/api2.php?action=create_user&login=foobar3130&password=6116b3f29c&name=Foo&surname=Bar&email=foobar%40gmail.com&languages=english&token=

Output of `echo "{$token}<br />";`

> pUCu2BUAE1heAyQ93fApfhvDE1bjKd

**Edit**
I added a check to see if `$start` was false, and it is false. I guess its not actually the token that gets echo'd because if I comment that line out, the string that I have for the token output still gets printed. I'm not sure what it would even be from.

**Edit 2**
I now have it returning xml but I am not sure how to parse it to get the token. It returns:

```
<xml><token>Fp1rYkds4fSuTAQxTvLvSiW5NE2FJz</token></xml>
```

Comment: And the output of echo "{$token}<br />"; ??

Comment: Did you set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option before curl_exec ?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the output of that one. Updated. @a1ex07 yes I did, I just didn't include that part of the script. I get a value for the token. it echos just fine.

Comment: Make sure that $res has a value? 
It's appending everything else, so if you aren't getting a value for $token, make sure that you are actually assigning it a value in the first place.

Comment: I'm definitely getting a value. I print it in the middle of the script, and it shows up just fine, it just doesn't show up after i append it to $url.

Comment: Ok, this may be stupid, but does it make a difference what order you put them in? If you put the `$url .= "&languages=english";` as the last line for instance, or `$url .= "&token=" . $token;` as the first line, does it still leave out the value? Last thing to try, if you put $token inside the string `$url .= "&token=$token";` does that make a difference?

Comment: Use xdebug (or Zend Debugger) in your IDE of choice, set some breakpoints and debug your code by stepping over your code, that will expose your bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your edit seems to confirm that `curl_exec()` isn't returning the data to you - it is sending it directly to the browser. Use the option `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to have it return the value to your variable.

Comment: I agree. So just add this line before you call curl_exec(): curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

Comment: This line was already in the script, I just didn't have it in the code  I pasted here.

Comment: @The.Anti.9, what is the output of `var_dump($res);`?

Comment: This is, of course, the right answer. I thought I had done it correctly, but as it turns out, i had CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER in quotes as you will see in my code. This, obviously, makes it not work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
ob_start();
echo "/www/api2.php?action=create_user";
echo "&login=" . urlencode($username);
echo "&password=" . urlencode($password);
echo "&name=" . urlencode($data['first_name']);
echo "&surname=" . urlencode($data['last_name']);
echo "&email=" . urlencode($email);
echo "&languages=english";
echo "&token=" . $token;
$url=ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

echo $url;
```

Answer (score 1):

From what your script shows, you are trying to parse the Token out of an XML result, with a fixed width of 37 characters.

Judging from your latest comment, that's where the problem lies.

A much better approach would be to use actual [XML DOM parsing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php) to get the token from the file.

Comment: Could you possibly give an example? I'm having trouble getting the DOMDocument stuff to work.

Comment: Oh yes, my mistake. I have included in my post now.